# Как получить коллекцию в контроллере

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Есть модель представления, состоит из требуемых для загрузки доков(описания и прочих данных для отображению клиента в форме). Мы передаем это в гет, проблем с отображением нету. Проблема начинается при получении в Post методе контроллера. Если указать тип NoLoadedDocTypeItem, то получаю только один экземпляр типа, но как быть, мне нужны все остальные экземпляры списка с файлами загружаемыми. Пытался ставить другие типы, везде приходит null. Есть какие то мысли в чем проблема?

Comment: А где `<form>`?

Comment: отредактировал пост

Answer (score 2):

Проблема заключалась в том что я перебирал модель через foreach, и мне в метод контроллера приходил только первый элемент коллекции(списка). Поменяв на for, проблема решилась и я получил то что хотел.